# database backup with cron jobs in cpanel

Tags: cron, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to take back up in my cpanel using cron jobs.

My script is like this

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=username --password=password --host=localhost dbname | gzip > /home/username/backups/dbbackup_$date.sql.gz
```

and in backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date +%Y%m%d_%k%M`;
  /usr/bin/mysqldump --user=username --password=password --host=localhost dbname | gzip > /home/username/backups/dbbackup_$date.sql.gz
```

and i have set the time for every 5 mins. But its not happening. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

can you give the exact line of cron job?
I tried this:

```
date=`date +%Y%m%d_%k%M`    
mysqldump -uroot -p12345 -h127.0.0.1 db | gzip > /home/ubuntu/root/db_$date.sql.gz
```

and it worked for me, may be there is some problem with your cron!!

To run every 5 minutes this is the syntax:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /home/ubuntu/root/backUpScript.sh
```

Comment: where are you getting error? Is dump working fine? just try to take dump first and see if you are getting the sql file. Then try to gzip tha sql file and check whether your getting a gzipped file of the sql file.

Comment: Works for me on shared hosting 10x.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to `chmod 777` on file `backUpScript.sh`, `cronjob` and folder dump database?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)
 you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add some apostrophe to your code for example

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=username --password=password --host=localhost dbname | gzip > /home/username/backups/dbbackup_$date.sql.gz
```

should be

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user='username' --password='password' --host='localhost' dbname | gzip > /home/username/backups/dbbackup_$date.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.
It does not give the ambiguous redirect error.

Put date as "$(date)"

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 db | gzip > /home/user/directory/db_"$(date)".sql.gz
```

Comment: This not an answer best posted as a comment